# Out pute file adds only one line

Tags: java

I have a text file delimited by vertical bar.
I want to create a new text file(comma delimited).
What i have below only writes a single line to the text file!
But the System.Out.PrintIn prints all the lines to the console!

Here is my code.

```
private void doImport(String sfile,String outfile, String gl, int period, String glacc,String contral) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    //java.util.List<Exports> pp= new ArrayList<Exports>();
    // imported data date format
     SimpleDateFormat fm =new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
     // output file date format
     SimpleDateFormat fm1 =new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    // file with data i want to change to new format
    File file = new File(sfile);
    // if file null?...add code in calling method to exit
    // first line headers...counter to track that
    int count=0;
    FileReader f= new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(f);
    String l =null;
    try {
        while((l=r.readLine()) != null)
        {
            count=count+1;
            // skip first line

            if (count>1)
            {
                // split data on | character
            String tokenizer="\\|";
            String[] s= l.split(tokenizer);
            // import only for references starting with f
            if(s[0].trim().startsWith("F"))
            {
                Date d= null;
                d= fm.parse(s[6].trim());
                Exports p= new  Exports();
                p.setPeriod(period);
                p.setExchangerate(1);
                p.setReference(s[0].trim());
                p.setGlcode(gl);
                p.setDate(fm1.format(d));
                p.setDescription(s[2].trim());
                p.setGlaccount(glacc);
                p.setContral(contral);
                p.setEmpty1(" ");
                p.setEmpty2(" ");
                p.setAmount(Double.parseDouble(s[9].trim()));
                p.setHomeamount(Double.parseDouble(s[9].trim()));
                p.setZero1(0);
                p.setZero2(0);
                p.setZ1(0);
                p.setZ2(0);
                p.setZ3(0);
                p.setOne(1);
                p.setEftnumber((s[5].trim()));  
                try
                    {

                    File f1 = new  File(outfile);
                    if (f1.exists()) {
                    // kill
                    f1.delete();
                    // create it then!
                    f1.createNewFile();
                    }

                    FileWriter writer= new FileWriter(f1);
                    BufferedWriter b= new BufferedWriter(writer);

                    b.write(p.toString());
                    b.newLine();
                    b.close();


            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(p.toString());
            }
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Any reasons why i get only one line added?

Ronald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code

```
                {

                File f1 = new  File(outfile);
                if (f1.exists()) {
                // kill
                f1.delete();
                // create it then!
                f1.createNewFile();
                }

                FileWriter writer= new FileWriter(f1);
                BufferedWriter b= new BufferedWriter(writer);

                b.write(p.toString());
                b.newLine();
                b.close();


        }
```

you are deleting a creating a new file for every iteration of your loop.

You could create your output file and Stream at the same time and place that you do for your input file and Stream

```
 File file = new File(sfile);
 FileReader f= new FileReader(file);
 BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(f);

File f1 = new  File(outfile);
if (f1.exists()) {
    // kill
    f1.delete();
    // create it then!
    f1.createNewFile();
 }

 FileWriter writer= new FileWriter(f1);
 BufferedWriter b= new BufferedWriter(writer);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the output file once, before the loop. Not in the loop.

```
private void doImport(String sfile,String outfile, String gl, int period, String glacc,String contral) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    //java.util.List<Exports> pp= new ArrayList<Exports>();
    // imported data date format
     SimpleDateFormat fm =new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
     // output file date format
     SimpleDateFormat fm1 =new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    // file with data i want to change to new format
    File file = new File(sfile);
    // if file null?...add code in calling method to exit
    // first line headers...counter to track that
    int count=0;
    FileReader f= new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(f);
    String l =null;
    try {
          File f1 = new  File(outfile);
          if (f1.exists()) {
                    // kill
                    f1.delete();
                    // create it then!
                    f1.createNewFile();
        }

        while((l=r.readLine()) != null)
        {
            count=count+1;
            // skip first line

            if (count>1)
            {
                // split data on | character
            String tokenizer="\\|";
            String[] s= l.split(tokenizer);
            // import only for references starting with f
            if(s[0].trim().startsWith("F"))
            {
                Date d= null;
                d= fm.parse(s[6].trim());
                Exports p= new  Exports();
                p.setPeriod(period);
                p.setExchangerate(1);
                p.setReference(s[0].trim());
                p.setGlcode(gl);
                p.setDate(fm1.format(d));
                p.setDescription(s[2].trim());
                p.setGlaccount(glacc);
                p.setContral(contral);
                p.setEmpty1(" ");
                p.setEmpty2(" ");
                p.setAmount(Double.parseDouble(s[9].trim()));
                p.setHomeamount(Double.parseDouble(s[9].trim()));
                p.setZero1(0);
                p.setZero2(0);
                p.setZ1(0);
                p.setZ2(0);
                p.setZ3(0);
                p.setOne(1);
                p.setEftnumber((s[5].trim()));  

                    FileWriter writer= new FileWriter(f1);
                    BufferedWriter b= new BufferedWriter(writer);

                    b.write(p.toString());
                    b.newLine();
                    b.close();


            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(p.toString());
            }
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```